# Form of the secret key in CP-ABE

Tags: secret-key

Could someone tell me how does the output of the KeyGen algorithm in CP-ABE look like? KeyGen(MK, S). The key generation algorithm will take as input a set of attributes S and output a key that identifies with that set. The algorithm first
chooses a random r ∈ Zp, and then random rj ∈ Zp for each attribute j ∈ S. Then it computes the key as 
SK = (D = g(α+r)/β, ∀j ∈ S : Dj = gr · H(j)rj ,D′j = grj )
When Dj and D'j have to be calculated, do we need to take it for the entire set of attributes S OR for each individual attribute in S?

Comment: Since the `j` in `Dj` refers to an attribute, you need a `D` and a `D'` for each attribute.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thank you very much.